# Table to datagridview

Tags: c#, html, datagridview

How to convert html table to datagridview in C#?
Let me know any reference for conversion.

Here is Html table.

```html
<table>
   
    <tr>
        <td>Living Room</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Size</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Duration</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>  
         
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import data from HTML table to DataTable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090626/import-data-from-html-table-to-datatable-in-c-sharp)