# Convert Html table data to a DataTable without looping

Tags: c#, datatable, html-table, ado.net

What is the best practice to convert html table data result to a new DataTable?
I don't use any loop like for or foreach for every result item.
There are any way in C# for copy table to Datatable?

Comment: Please post some code, what's your _"Html table"_ look like?

Comment: html table is simple tr td format.
like <table><tr><td>name</name><td>Date</td></tr><tr><td>test</td><td>01/01/2018</td></tr> So all <tr> row are save in data table but without using any loop.

Comment: Do you mean https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx or https://datatables.net/ ?

Comment: Why the aversion to looping? If you want to do something to *n* things you need to do it *n* times.  Here is an example use HAP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090626/import-data-from-html-table-to-datatable-in-c-sharp

Comment: I m talking about https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can't want to use looping.